# Responsive Email Template - Outlook 2013 Breaking Layout

Tags: responsive-design, html-email, fluid-layout, hybrid

This layout is breaking in Outlook only. I can't remember where I got the template from, so I can't give credit where it's due, but I believe it's one of Lee Munroe's templates. I can't figure out why it's breaking in Outlook 2013 and it's a simple one-column layout. I have a more complex one-column layout that I'm using with the same framework, and that one gives me no trouble at all. But when I tried to parse it down into a simpler layout, I cannot get it to play nicely with Outlook. Any ideas? Self-taught coder so I could be missing something simple. I know Outlook can't handle max-width, but this template was supposed to be Outlook ready.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>A Message from the CEO</title>
  <style type="text/css">

img {
  border: none;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
  max-width: 100%; }

.img-block {
  display: block; }

body {
  font-family: open sans, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; }

table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
  mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
  width: 100%; }
  table td {
    font-family: open sans, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    vertical-align: top; }

body {
  background-color: #F6F6F6;
  Margin: 0;
  padding: 0; }

.body {
  background-color: #F6F6F6;
  width: 100%; }

.container {
  Margin: 0 auto !important;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 30px;
  width: auto !important;
  width: 600px; }

.content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  Margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 0px; }

.main {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 100%; }

.wrapper {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 30px; }

.header {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  Margin-bottom: 0px;
  Margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  width: 100%; }
  .header > table {
    min-width: 100%; }

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  Margin: 0; }

h1 {
  font-family: open sans, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #7D1745;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.4;
  Margin-bottom: 10px; }

h2 {
  font-family: open sans, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #3C708F;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.4;
  Margin-bottom: 15px; }

h3 {
  font-family: open sans, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #7D1745;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.4;
  Margin-bottom: 15px; }

h4 {
  font-family: open sans, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #454646;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.4;
  Margin-bottom: 15px; }

ul,
ol {
  font-family: open sans, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #454646;
  Margin: 0;
  Margin-bottom: 20px; }
  p li,
  ul li,
  ol li {
    list-style-position: outside;
    Margin-left: 15px;
    padding: 0;
    text-indent: 0; }
ul,
ol {
  Margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  text-indent: 0; }

a:link {
  font-family: open sans, sans-serif;
  color: #3C708F;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none; }

a:hover {
  font-family: open sans, sans-serif;
  color: #56A2CC;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none; }

a:active {
  font-family: open sans, sans-serif;
  color: #3C708F;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none; }

a:visited {
  font-family: open sans, sans-serif;
  color: #3C708F;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none; }

.preheader {
  color: transparent;
  display: none;
  height: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  max-width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  mso-hide: all;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 24px !important;
    Margin-bottom: 10px !important; }
  h2 {
    font-size: 21px !important;
    Margin-bottom: 10px !important; }
  h3 {
    font-size: 21px !important;
    Margin-bottom: 10px !important; }
  h4 {
    font-size: 18px !important;
    Margin-bottom: 10px !important; }
  p,
  ul,
  ol,
  td,
  span,
  a {
    font-size: 16px !important; }
  .wrapper {
    padding: 10px !important; }
  .content {
    padding: 0 !important; }
  .container {
    padding: 0 !important;
    width: 100% !important; }
  .header {
    Margin-bottom: 10px !important; }
  .main {
    border-left-width: 0 !important;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    border-right-width: 0 !important; }
  .img-responsive {
    height: auto !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    width: auto !important; } }

@media all {
  .ExternalClass {
    width: 100%; }
  .ExternalClass,
  .ExternalClass p,
  .ExternalClass span,
  .ExternalClass font,
  .ExternalClass td,
  .ExternalClass div {
    line-height: 100%; }
  .apple-link a {
    color: inherit !important;
    font-family: inherit !important;
    font-size: inherit !important;
    font-weight: inherit !important;
    line-height: inherit !important;
    text-decoration: none !important; } }
    </style>

<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<xml>
<o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
<o:AllowPNG/>
<o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
</o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
</xml>
<![endif]-->

</head>
<body class="">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="body">
    <tr>
      <td class="container">
        <div class="content">
        <!-- START CENTERED WHITE CONTAINER -->
        <span class="preheader">Read the latest update from Johnson Financial Group.</span>
        <table class="main" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td><img src="https://app.subscribermail.com/images/pp/56502968/2018_Images/Jim_Popp_600px.jpg" title="A Message from the CEO" alt="Header Image" width="600" class="img-responsive" border="0"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="wrapper">
              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <h1>Headline</h1>
                    <p>Content here. Blah blah blah blah.</p>
                    <h2>Subheadline 1</h2>
                    <p>Content here. Blah blah blah blah.</p>
                    <h3>Subheadline 2</h3>
                    <p>Content here. Blah blah blah blah. <a href="https://www.johnsonbank.com/" title="Johnson Bank" style="color: #3C708F; font-size: 1em; font-weight: 700; text-decoration: none;" target="_blank"><strong style="font-weight: 700;">Read More</strong></a></p>
                    <h4>Subheadline 3</h4>
                    <p>Content here. Blah blah blah blah.</p>
                    <p><img src="https://app.subscribermail.com/images/pp/56502968/2018_Images/Jim_Popp.png" title="Jim Popp, CEO Johnson Financial Group" alt="Jim Popp" width="100" class="img-responsive" border="0" /></p>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="wrapper">
              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                  <td align="center">
                    <img src="https://app.subscribermail.com/images/pp/56502968/2018_Images/JFG-HRZ-Web-200px.png" title="Johnson Financial Group" alt="JFG Logo" width="200" class="img-responsive" border="0" /><br />
                    <div>&nbsp;</div>
                    <a href="https://www.johnsonbank.com/Personal/Banking" title="Personal Banking | Johnson Bank" style="color: #3C708F; font-size: 1em; font-weight: 700; text-decoration: none;" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><strong style="font-weight: 700;">BANKING</strong></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a href="https://www.johnsonbank.com/Personal/Wealth" title="Personal Wealth | Johnson Bank" style="color: #3C708F; font-size: 1em; font-weight: 700; text-decoration: none;" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><strong style="font-weight: 700;">WEALTH</strong></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a href="https://www.johnsonbank.com/Personal/Insurance" title="Personal Insurance | Johnson Insurance" style="color: #3C708F; font-size: 1em; font-weight: 700; text-decoration: none;" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><strong style="font-weight: 700;">INSURANCE</strong></a><br />
                    <div>&nbsp;</div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <!-- END CENTERED WHITE CONTAINER -->
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have the other template that's working fine for me in Outlook 2013. If anyone wants to look at that for comparison, please let me know. It's made from the same code base so maybe that will help point to the answer. The only thing I can think of is that I combined the tables incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

Your problems extend far beyond Outlook 2013. These problems are occurring in Outlook 2007-2016, Windows 10 Mail and Android devices.

The problem resides within the `<style>` sheet. If you comment out your style sheet, everything works fine when tested in Litmus.

The `<style>` sets the desktop `<table>` width to `width: 100%;`. But you don't want your tables at 100%, you wanted them at 600px.

```
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
  mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
  /*width: 100%; <-- don't use this */
  width: 600px;
}
```

Go through your `<style>` sheet and change `width:100%;` values to `width: 600px;`. This includes `@media all`, but you can skip `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)` since those table values should be 100% width.

You need to figure out a way to make the controlling table 100% width and center the container tables in the parent table.

**Other Issues**

Your preview text is not working in Android. It's showing up and I think you want to hide it.

Open Sans will never work in Outlook or Gmail, since neither works with web fonts. You can use it for Apple, IOS, Android, AOL and other clients. I strongly suggest you use a link to a style sheet like this:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
```

Add that to your `<head>`.

Use this instead in your style sheet for Open Sans as recommended by Google Fonts:

```
font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
```

You should set a default fallback font, which is currently set to sans-serif to ensure the right font is used. I suggest adding one more web safe font as a fallback for consistency, because Outlook has a bad habit of reverting to Times New Roman and you don't want a serif typeface.

Good luck.

Edit: I edited this answer because I did not make it clear you could skip editing values for this media query: `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)`.

Comment: Pretty much most of this.

Comment: That's interesting because that's exactly how the layout came. I did not edit the table settings or media queries. The container class is meant to be at 100% on the media query side from what I can tell, but it looks like it should be coded with 600 px on the class itself now that you mention it. I didn't want to mess with the template too much so I left all of those styles alone. I will try making those adjustments to the 100% like you mentioned.

Comment: To me it looks like the author intended the tables to be 100% for smaller screens, but the container is supposed to control it for larger screens:

    .container {
      Margin: 0 auto !important;
      max-width: 600px;
      padding: 30px;
      width: auto !important;
      width: 600px; }

Comment: @KatrinaNeveri I'm sure the author intended for mobile devices to be 100%. But you're code forces desktop browsers to be 100%. Outlook is less savvy than modern clients. That's why I said change the `<style>` sheet and the `@media all` to address desktop clients. I figured you'd know enough about email development to leave the `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)` alone.

Comment: I wasn't going to change the media only screen and (max-width: 600px) item at all. That's not what I'm referring to in my comment either. What I was saying is that everything you see above was the default settings applied by the person who created the template. And they seemed to have the reverse of what you were suggesting, where the tables are responsive but the container controls everything to 600px width. There's nothing controlling table width under media only screen and (max-width: 600px) from what I can see, unless that's what the .container tag is doing there, which is at 100%.

Comment: Unless the media query name itself "max-width: 600px" also controls table width. Just seems odd to apply constraints on the table when they have a .container class that does that. I don't know enough about media queries to say so I will just take your advice!

Comment: @KatrinaNeveri Any values in `@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)` control the page when the width is 600px or less. That is why the height for `<h1>` changes from `font-size: 1.4em;` for desktop to 24px for 600px and lower widths. - https://litmus.com/blog/understanding-media-queries-in-html-email